# Why do I get a segfault when trying to access members of struct?

Tags: c, dll, operating-system, queue, valgrind

I am getting a segmentation fault whenever I try to print the value stored within a struct. Using Valgrind, I was able to narrow it down a bit to one block of code, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Am I initializing my struct incorrectly?

Whenever I run valgrind, it tells me that there is an *invalid write of size 8* where I say *newList->data = d*.

```
typedef struct List {
  struct List *np[Ends];        // next/prev neighbors
  Data data;
} *List;

typedef void *Data;

static void put(Data d) {
  List newList = malloc(sizeof(List));
  newList->data = d;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of why it's bad practice to `typedef` a pointer.

Because `List` is defined as an alias for `struct List *`, `sizeof(List)` gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the struct.  As a result, you're not allocating enough memory.

You instead want either `malloc(sizeof(struct List))` or (preferably) `malloc(sizeof *newlist)`

Comment: Yeah, if you are going to typedef pointers, (eg. to avoid ****someType, not a bad practice at all:), then make it obvious, eg 'pList' or 'ListPtr'.